# Need help about UNIX epoch

Tags: php, epoch

I have been googling last 2 hours and I figured out that the problem is related to Unix epoch.

What I want to do is a count down in php. As you can see below, (Gave them letters to refer them easily).

B minus C is equal to A. But it gives me this: **"31/12/69 19:00:08"** but I would like to have **"00/00/00 00:00:08"**.

(A) 31/12/69 19:00:08 = (B) 25/03/15 00:13:26 - (C) 25/03/15 00:13:18

And this problem cause a problem in my count down. When I wanna count down from 10:00 (Min, Sec), it starts counting down from 60:00 and when it reaches 50:00 count down stops. So it works! after 10 min it stops but the problem is, it counts down from 60. So, it is caused from unix epoch I guess. If I can initialize the unnecessary part, in the date, to zero or null I can fix the problem.

---

```
$pastTime = $currentTime - $row['startTime'];
            if($pastTime >= $row['durationTime']){
                $processStatus = "Completed";
                $remainingTime = 0;
            }else{
                $processStatus = "in Process";
                $remainingTime = $durationTime - $pastTime;
            }
            echo "<td>" . date('i:s', $remainingTime) . "</td>";
            echo "<td>$processStatus</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
```

This is some part of my code. So, I am having problem when I do this; `date('i:s', $remainingTime)`. All the variables you see, contains seconds which is generated by `time()` function.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet, preferably an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org), of the behavior you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

You're not sharing any code, but I take it that you subtract two timestamps to figure out the difference in seconds, and then format the result as a unix timestamp.

The problem is in that last step. When you subtract the two numbers, you do get a (mostly) correct number, but then you decide to use (presumably) `date()` for display.

Instead, you may want to try to use two `DateTime` objects, use `diff` to get the difference (as a `DateInterval` object) and then use [`DateInterval::format`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) to get the format you actually want.